# Get the same Data from different tables

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal Report needs quantities from four different tables - POINVD, OEINVD, PORCPD, and OECRDD. All the tables have the desired quantity field. If the Source data is PO, I get the quantity from POINVD. If source data is OE, then from OEINVD.

What formula can I use to get the quantity from all the tables?

I have tried the following :

```
If IsNull({OEINVD.QTYSHIPPED}) Then
   {OECRDD.QTYRETURN}
Else If IsNull({POINVL.OQRECEIVED}) Then
   {OEINVD.QTYSHIPPED}
Else If IsNull({PORCPL.SQRECEIVED}) Then
   {POINVH1.RQRECEIVED}
Else If IsNull({POINVH1.RQRECEIVED}) Then
   {POINVL.SQRECEIVED}
Else {POINVL.OQRECEIVED}
```

Comment: are you using all tables in single report and also how do you know which table to use at runtime?

Comment: yes i,m using all the tables in single report. basically the report is for all costing hence at runtime it should go to all tables and depending on the parameter, it should get the information from all tables

Comment: Can you explain what values does parameter contains...based on that we can write condition

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be easier to UNION the common fields from the 4 tables together into one source table for your report.  You can add a new column showing each row's source table, if you need it.

Comment: @ Beth, how do i do the UNION? i am new to crystal reports